# Retrieve the method in Router 6 useFetcher Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have no other option but to call the submit method for a fetcher in a handler. It's accessing the correct action method in the routers however I'm unable to pass the method to the action, i.e. `method='POST` defined in the Form. How to access the method of `fetch.Form` inside the handler?

```
const fetcher = useFetcher()

const handlerLogin = useCallback(async () => {
  console.log(fetcher.formMethod) //-> outputting undefined
  fetcher.submit({ value: 'social' }, { method: fetcher.formMethod })
},[])
    
return (
  <Card className={styles.loginCard}>
    <fetcher.Form method='POST' action='/'>
      ..............
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, you pass the method to the `handlerLogin` function:

```js
const fetcher = useFetcher();

const handlerLogin = useCallback(async (formMethod) => {
  fetcher.submit({ value: 'social' }, { method: formMethod });
}, []);

return (
  <Card className={styles.loginCard}>
    <fetcher.Form
      method='POST'
      action='/'
    >
      {/* other parts ... */}
      <button onClick={() => handlerLogin(fetcher.formMethod)}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </fetcher.Form>
  </Card>
);
```

Comment: This seems to be working however while it's passing to the action method, for some reason the data now isn't being passed. Any ideas? I created a codesandbox showing this: https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-tdd-y5cdvd   ... if you look at the console POST is printing out but not the formData()

Answer (score 1):

`handlerLogin` is being memoized and is closing over the `fetcher` value from the initial render cycle. `fetcher` is an external dependency so it should be included in the `useCallback` hook's dependency array.

```js
const fetcher = useFetcher();

const handlerLogin = useCallback(() => {
  console.log(fetcher.formMethod);
  fetcher.submit({ value: 'social' }, { method: fetcher.formMethod });
}, [fetcher]);
```

Since this is likely only passed to the RRD `Form` component and not down as a prop to children I suspect the `useCallback` hook is even necessary and could likely be removed.

```js
const fetcher = useFetcher();

const handlerLogin = () => {
  console.log(fetcher.formMethod);
  fetcher.submit({ value: 'social' }, { method: fetcher.formMethod });
};
```